# What exactly is stored in "output" variable in the FIR Filter code below?

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response

What exactly is stored in "output" variable in the FIR Filter code below?

```
      float filter (float value){
          for (int i = ntaps-1; i>0; i--){
              buffer[i] = buffer[i-1];
          }
          buffer[0] = value;
          for (int i = 0; i<ntaps; i++){
              output += buffer[i]*h[i];
           }
           return ouput;
        }
```

Comment: That's a verbatim duplicate to a question you asked 5 days ago, just about `output` instead of `buffer`; already has an answer. You really just need to learn C; if you can't say what output is after having gotten the answer about `buffer`, then I'm sorry, you really just need to read a C introduction.

Answer (score 0):

The `output` variable holds the current output value given the current input value `value`. It is just the weighted sum of the current and `ntaps-1` past input values. Note that this is not the most optimized version of an FIR filter routine.

Comment: What exactly will the "output" variable be storing when the "filter" routine is run consecutively with different values of the "value" variable.

Comment: @B.Han: Each time you call it, it holds the new output value corresponding to the new and past input values.

Comment: How are the new values of the "output" variable related to the old values of the "output" variable?

Comment: @B.Han: They aren't related to the old output values. It's not a recursive filter.

Comment: When I run the function "filter" the I first time I get a value say "output1". When I run the function "filter" again I get another value say "output2". Please clarify how "output1" and "output2" are related...

Comment: @B.Han: They're just outputs of a standard FIR filter; each output sample is a weighted sum of the current and `ntaps-1` previous input values.